# Can we get user profile page using user_id in the URL?

Tags: users, profiles

The current default profile page is like `example.com/user/johndoe`. But can I access the page via `example.com/user/?user_id=21` where 21 is johndoe's `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_the_author_meta()` function for this purpose. Use the `get_the_author_meta('ID')` for only get the ID.

Ensure you check the page first with `is_author()` function before getting the ID.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/

Comment: Actually I was hoping to know how I could construct a URL such as example.com/user/?user_id=21

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your intentions but if you need to create a url of type /user/user_id and this url will also run to that user's profile page then you can try these steps:

1. Create a custom teamplate file to handle the display of user information.
2. Create a request handler function, if the user accesses the url with the path you requested, it will run the other custom template file, for example here is when the user enters the path with the url /user
3. You can make use of this template by the code below.
   Note that your custom template file needs to write handling functions to get user information according to that user_id.

```
add_action('template_include', function($template) {
    $link = trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    $url = $link_array[0];
  if ( $url === 'user' ) {
     // load the file if exists
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    // return get_stylesheet_directory();
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom_template.php';
    exit;
  }else{
    return $template;
  }
});
```